# What happens when an Azure Scheduled WebJob throws an unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

My case is that the job will run for about twelve hours every 60 seconds and then it will just stop and I have to manually start it again.  My web job is just a plain CLI that is not using the SDK.  It seems as if my web job is being disabled if I have an unhandled exception and then I have to manually start it again.  Is this a correct behavior?

Comment: Are you using the Azure Scheduler or the CRON approach? Both are described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

Comment: I am using a CRON of "0 * * * * *" to run once every minute.  It just seems if you don't handle all of the exceptions then job will not run again and I'm wondering if that is the case.  I can't seem to find any hints from the documentation or by searching.

Comment: I suppose I should note that I'm assuming an exception might be happening.  This job will run for many hours reliably on each minute and then we'll look at the WebJob details and it'll be stopped.

Comment: Do you have Always On enabled on the Web App?

Comment: We just found out about Always On and then I seen your comment. Thank you!

Comment: We did added the Always On and made a watch dog to make sure it is running and we have not had any issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found in the comments, the root issue was that the Web App did not have the Always On option enabled. After enabling it, the issue went away.